# Using jQuery Date Picker causes: <f:convertDateTime> Parent not an instance of ValueHolder

Tags: jsf, converters, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an bean `vacationRequestBean` with `startdate` and `enddate` fields of `java.util.Date` type. I am using jQuery Date Picker in my `index.xhtml` for those fields. Format of the date picker is `MM-dd-yyyy`.

```
<script>
   $(function() {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
   });
 </script>

<h:inputText id="date" class="datepicker" value="#{vacationRequestBean.startdate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" type="date"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="date" class="datepicker" value="#{vacationRequestBean.enddate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" type="date"/>
</h:inputText>
```

I get the following error:

> <f:convertDateTime> Parent not an instance of ValueHolder

How can I store the selected date picker value?

Comment: First of all the jQuery selector should be `$('.datepicker')` to match the classes, since there is no ID `datepicker` (# is an id selector). Second of all the inputText attribute `class` should be `styleClass`. Check out the [TLD of h:inputText](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/jsp/h/inputText.html). Other than that - are you bean members of type `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue resolved after removing the `<f:convertDateTime>`